# Object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' after validation in Django view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to make a registration page for my project. Standard model `User` is not enough for me, so I created another model named `Profile`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='М',
                       verbose_name='Пол')
    third_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Отчество')
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GRADE_CHOICES, default='1',
                         verbose_name='Класс обучения')
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=7, verbose_name='Возраст',
                                       validators=[
                                           MaxValueValidator(100),
                                           MinValueValidator(4)
                                       ]
                                       )
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                           verbose_name='Учебное заведение',
                           blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    interest = models.ManyToManyField(OlympiadSubject,
                                  verbose_name='Интересующие предметы')
```

On both `User` and `Profile` I created a `ModelForm`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('third_name', 'sex', 'grade', 'age', 'school', 'interest')
```

And wrote a view for registration:

```
def create_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        User.objects.create(**user_form.cleaned_data)
        Profile.objects.create(**profile_form.cleaned_data, user=User)
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
        profile_form.add_error('__all__', 'Данные введены неверно!')
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
return render(request, 'users/profile_create.html', {
    'user_form': user_form,
    'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

and of course I have a template for that:

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %} Some text {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Сохранить изменения</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

but i get the same error every time:
`ProfileForm object has no attribute cleaned_data`
Don't know how to fix it.

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Sorry, if I wrote something incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to capture the form data that are coming with the POST request.
You may write:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define the forms in case of POST request, you don't bind the data to the forms. Since the forms you have created are empty, there is no cleaned_data.

Try

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST) # the request.POST part binds the data to the form
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: Might lead is rather soft here. It is not the request type, but actually the data from the POST request. OP is creating new empty forms with the empty parens.

Comment: @progmatico Agree, I've edited the response to make the explanation more precise.